# Wrapping C library in Cython: Expected ')', found '*'

Tags: cython

I want to wrap a library with the following header file:

```
#include "rbtree.h"

struct interval_tree_node {
    struct rb_node rb;
    unsigned long start;    /* Start of interval */
    unsigned long last; /* Last location _in_ interval */
    unsigned long __subtree_last;
};

extern void
interval_tree_insert(struct interval_tree_node *node, struct rb_root *root);

extern void
interval_tree_remove(struct interval_tree_node *node, struct rb_root *root);

extern struct interval_tree_node *
interval_tree_iter_first(struct rb_root *root,
             unsigned long start, unsigned long last);

extern struct interval_tree_node *
interval_tree_iter_next(struct interval_tree_node *node,
            unsigned long start, unsigned long last);
```

This is my intervaltree.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "src/intervaltree.h":

    struct interval_tree_node:
        struct rb_node

    void interval_tree_insert(struct interval_tree_node *node, struct rb_root *root)

    void interval_tree_remove(struct interval_tree_node *node, struct rb_root *root)

    struct interval_tree_node * interval_tree_iter_first(struct rb_root *root, unsigned long start, unsigned long last)

    struct interval_tree_node * interval_tree_iter_next(struct interval_tree_node *node, unsigned long start, unsigned long last)
```

And here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("intervaltree", ["intervaltree.pyx"])])
)
```

My `intervaltree.pyx` is just empty, or

```
cimport intervaltree
```

When I run `python setup.py install` I get the following error:

```
    Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef extern from "src/intervaltree.h":

    struct interval_tree_node:
        struct rb_node

    void interval_tree_insert(struct interval_tree_node *node, struct rb_root *root)
                                                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

intervaltree.pxd:6:56: Expected ')', found '*'
```

Since the examples in the docs [Defining external declarations](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#defining-external-declarations) use the syntax

```
int queue_push_head(Queue* queue, QueueValue data)
```

not

```
int queue_push_head(Queue *queue, QueueValue data)
```

I tried to change that part, but it did not seem to help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `cdef` in front of `struct interval_tree_node` so Cython isn't recognising it as a type:

```
cdef struct interval_tree_node
    rb_node rb # assuming you've also defined rb_node somewhere
```

[The relevant documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#styles-of-struct-union-and-enum-declaration).

Similarly, you want to write `interval_tree_node`, not `struct interval_tree_node` in your Cython code.

---

Update from OP. This is how it was supposed to look in the end:

```
cdef extern from "src/rbtree.h":

    cdef struct rb_root:
        pass

cdef extern from "src/interval_tree.h":

    cdef struct interval_tree_node:
        pass

    void interval_tree_insert(interval_tree_node *node, rb_root *root)

    void interval_tree_remove(interval_tree_node *node, rb_root *root)

    interval_tree_node * interval_tree_iter_first(rb_root *root, unsigned long start, unsigned long last)

    interval_tree_node * interval_tree_iter_next(interval_tree_node *node, unsigned long start, unsigned long last)
```